# JQ query extraction

Tags: jq

First off thanks to everyone who takes time to answer questions for us who are learning or struggling. I have this code that works as I need, I had help from knittl earlier.

```
    jq -r '["Username", "Full name", "Superuser", "Active"],
     > (.User[]
     > | select(.is_superuser)
     > | [ .username, .full_name, .is_superuser, .is_active ])
     > | @csv' lbc.noprod1.xxx.json > lbc.noprod1.xxx_Superuser.csv
```

I have tried to adjust it so that I can use the same concept but to get other information and have this

```
     jq -r '["Interface Name", "Vlan ID", "IP address", "Subnet Mask"],
      (.ServiceEngine[].data_vnics[].vlan_interfaces[]
      | [ .if_name, .vlan_id])
      (.ServiceEngine[].data_vnics[].vlan_interfaces[].vnic_networks[].ip[].ip_addr[]
      |  [.addr])
      (.ServiceEngine[].data_vnics[].vlan_interfaces[].vnic_networks[].ip[]
      | [.mask])
      | @csv' 20221004_lbc.prod1.xxx.json > 20221004_lbc.prod1.xxx_VNIC.csv
```

I receive the error below

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 4:
(.ServiceEngine[].data_vnics[].vlan_interfaces[].vnic_networks[].ip[].ip_addr[]
jq: 1 compile error

If it helps this is an extract from the JSON with fields that aren't relevant removed but all formatting kept

```
    "ServiceEngine": [
    {
        "data_vnics": [
            {
                "vlan_interfaces": [
                    {
                        "if_name": "bond1.109",
                        "vlan_id": 109,
                        "vnic_networks": [
                            {
                                "ctlr_alloc": false,
                                "ip": {
                                    "ip_addr": {
                                        "addr": "123.123.123.123",
                                        "type": "V4"
                                    },
                                    "mask": 24
                                },
                                "mode": "STATIC"
                            }
                        ],
                        "vrf_ref": "/api/vrfcontext/?tenant=admin&name=branch-pci-client-vlan109&cloud=Default-Cloud"
                    },
                    {
                        "dhcp_enabled": true,
                        "enabled": true,
                        "if_name": "bond1.1622",
                        "ip6_autocfg_enabled": true,
                        "is_mgmt": false,
                        "vlan_id": 1622,
                        "vnic_networks": [
                            {
                                "ctlr_alloc": false,
                                "ip": {
                                    "ip_addr": {
                                        "addr": "456.456.456.456",
                                        "type": "V4"
                                    },
                                    "mask": 22
                                },
                                "mode": "STATIC"
                            }
                        ],
                        "vrf_ref": "/api/vrfcontext/?tenant=admin&name=onprem-pci-prod-vlan1622&cloud=Default-Cloud"
                    },
```

As always if you have any tips and suggestions I would be greatful.

Kind regards

Comment: Please show a valid (but still reduced) JSON document. Also, what is your expected output? Looks like you are missing commas between each group of parentheses, but I doubt that the program will give you the output that you expect. Why? Because there is too much repetition going on and you will likely end up with information duplicated or separated into "blocks".

Comment: @knittl I have edited the above. I hope the code reads better.

Comment: @asthmatic_weasel can you please still make that JSON a valid JSON object? One that can be fed into `jq .` and jq would pretty-print it without errors? AND include the expected output

Comment: @pmf Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that and it ended up with no results populating. The most have I have got so far is the first two columns populating which is the output from the first ( )

Comment: @knittl thanks as always, unfortunately I am not skilled enough to remove 50 lines of code from 14000 and make it then work as a stand alone JSON. I am trying to use a JSON editing tool online to get it to play nicely. Once I have it working ill update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you are looking for this:

```
["Interface Name", "Vlan ID", "IP address", "Subnet Mask"],
(
    .ServiceEngine[].data_vnics[].vlan_interfaces[]
    | . as { $if_name, $vlan_id }
    | .vnic_networks[].ip
    | [ $if_name, $vlan_id, .ip_addr.addr, .mask]
)
| @csv
```

or

```
["Interface Name", "Vlan ID", "IP address", "Subnet Mask"],
(
    .ServiceEngine[].data_vnics[].vlan_interfaces[]
    | [ .if_name, .vlan_id ] + (.vnic_networks[].ip | [.ip_addr.addr, .mask])
)
| @csv
```

or

```
["Interface Name", "Vlan ID", "IP address", "Subnet Mask"],
(
    .ServiceEngine[].data_vnics[].vlan_interfaces[]
    | { if_name, vlan_id, ips: .vnic_networks[].ip }
    | [ .if_name, .vlan_id, (.ips|.ip_addr.addr, .mask) ]
)
| @csv
```

All three generate the same CSV with one line per IP. Interface name and VLAN id will be printed multiple times if they contain more than one IP.

Comment: Thanks for the guide there, I think I can see what I have done wrong, it looks like its my ( placement. I appreciate the help you are giving me.

Comment: For awareness @knittl all 3 of your suggestions worked for my use case. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @asthmatic_weasel glad to help. Yes, all three programs are equivalent and will produce the same output. Different people might prefer one over the other (readability, expressiveness, number of characters, …)